# Know which directory is "mount -o bind" by asking the kernel (Linux)

Tags: linux, mount, linux-kernel

If I do `mount -o bind /my/dir /mnt/tmp`, I can see the content of `/my/dir` within `/mnt/temp`. However, if I type `cat /proc/mounts`, I get the following output:

```
/dev/sda7 /my ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda7 /mnt/tmp ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

As you can see, I know that `sda7` is the underlying device, but I don't know which directory within that filesystem is "mount bound" in `/mnt/temp`.

How can I know that without typing `mount` which doesn't rely on the kernel but on `/etc/mtab`? **I'd like to get the information from the kernel itself.**

**EDIT:** it would be nice if the solution could also work for directories bound *at mount time* from `/etc/fstab` with this kind of line: `/my/dir /mnt/temp none bind 0 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this info from `/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
# mkdir -p /my/dir
# mkdir /mnt/temp
# mount -o bind /my/dir /mnt/temp
# grep temp /proc/self/mountinfo 
26 22 202:1 /my/dir /mnt/temp rw,noatime - ext3 /dev/xvda1 rw,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=0,data=ordered
```

Here is the patch that implemented this in the kernel: https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/1/29/136

You could also use the `findmnt` command:

```
# findmnt /mnt/temp
TARGET    SOURCE              FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/temp /dev/xvda1[/my/dir] ext3   rw,noatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=0,data=ordered
```

**EDIT**: I also verified that this method works when mounted via `/etc/fstab`.

```
# tail -1 /etc/fstab 
/my/dir  /mnt/temp  none  bind  0 0
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, however, it doesn't work if the bound mount is done at boot type from `/etc/fstab` as follows. fstab has: `/my/dir /home none bind 0 0` ; but `$ grep /home /proc/self/mountinfo` yields `20 11 8:7 /home /home rw,noatime - ext4 /dev/sda7 rw,data=ordered` and `$ findmnt /home` says `/home  /dev/sda7[/home] ext4   rw,noatime,data=ordered`

Comment: The result is the same for me regardless of whether the mount is done during boot via fstab, or after the fact.  What kernel version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, you're right... I was confused because if `/my` is a mount point, then `/proc/self/mountinfo` reports something like `20 11 8:7 /dir /home [...] /dev/sda7` with `sda7` being the `/my` partition. I will delete my comments if you delete yours. :)